# Python: Dictionary into Json file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
a = {'index': [1, 2, 3], 'similar': [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]], 'markets': [['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]}
keys = ['index', 'similar', 'markets']
```

And I want it to transform it into a json file

like

```
{'index': 'elem1' , "similar" :  [ {'elem0' 'elem2'} ]  , "markets" : [{'marketA', 'marketC'}] }
{'index': 'elem2  , "similar" :  [ {'elem1' 'elem2'} ]  , "markets" : [{'marketB', 'marketC'}] }
{'index': 'elem3' , "similar" :  [ {'elem2' 'elem1'} ]  , "markets" : [{'marketA', 'marketB'}] }
```

I currently have

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(a, fp)
```

But I am not sure how to get the desired outcome

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Your output shows multiple json blobs separated by newlines. So, its not "a json file" but "a file containing many line-separated json objects". Is that what you want? if so, how do you get those multiple dicts? You could open the file in append mode multiple times or write multiple dicts at once.

Comment: yes I want a file containing many json objects

Comment: Okay, so you want to do some sort of a transform. You should show us what you've done so far and maybe include some hints on what the transform is. SO is not generally a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to adapt the structure of your currently desired output. Your similar and market arrays contain sets ([{'elem0', 'elem2' }]) which is of course not possible in JSON.

I have written the necessary piece of code for you.

```
import json
f = {'index': [1, 2, 3], 'similar': [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]], 'markets': [['A', 'C'], ['B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]}
res = {}
for k,v in f.iteritems():
    for i, s_v in enumerate(v):
        if not res.get(i):
            res[i] = {}
        if k == 'markets':
            prefix = 'market'
        else:
            prefix = 'elem'
        if isinstance(s_v, int):
            res[i][k] = '%s%s' % (prefix, s_v)
        else:
            res[i][k] = [[]]
            for _s_v in s_v:
                res[i][k][0].append('%s%s' % (prefix, _s_v))
            res[i][k][0] = res[i][k][0]
res = [v for k, v in res.iteritems()]
print json.dumps(res)

.. [{"index": "elem1", "similar": [["elem0", "elem2"]], "markets": [["marketA", "marketC"]]}, {"index": "elem2", "similar": [["elem1", "elem2"]], "markets": [["marketB", "marketC"]]}, {"index": "elem3", "similar": [["elem2", "elem1"]], "markets": [["marketA", "marketB"]]}]
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion however it does not print the desire output. Your solution prints {"index": "elem1"}, {"index": "elem2"}, {"index": "elem3"}, {"similar": [["elem0", "elem2"]]}, {"similar": [["elem1", "elem2"]]}, {"similar": [["elem2", "elem1"]]}, {"markets": [["marketA", "marketC"]]}, {"markets": [["marketB", "marketC"]]}, {"markets": [["marketA", "marketB"]]}]

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please notice that your desired output is not JSON compliant, JSON can't hold tuples / sets ([{'elem1', 'elem2'}]) => has to be output the following way: [['elem1', 'elem2']] or alternatively: ['elem1', 'elem2']

Comment: Please mark the question as correct if this does it.